# sqlite3_go18.go:18:10: undefined: SQLiteConn

Tags: golang, компилятор

Хочу скомпилировать программу под 32 бита:

```
set GOOS=windows
set GOARCH=386
```

Установлен `mingw-w64` https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/ но все равно вылетает ошибка `sqlite3_go18.go:18:10: undefined: SQLiteConn`.

Comment: А если не указывать архитектуру, то компилируется?

Comment: @suit да, компилируется